# c# WPF linq GroupJoin to DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I have lists with emps and depts. I need to show in DataGrid all depts (also these without any emps) with their emps.

For now I have showing all depts to DataGrid, but i have no clue how to add emps and show it in DataGrid.

Propably i need something like this in DataGrid:

```
-dept1
    -emp1
    -emp2
-dept2
    -emp3
...
```

```cs
List<Emp> Emps = new List<Emp>();
List<Dept> Depts = new List<Dept>();
```

```cs
DataGrid.ItemsSource = Depts.GroupJoin(Emps, dept => dept.Deptno, emp => emp.Deptno, 
                (dept, emp) => dept);
```

```xml
<DataGrid Name="DataGrid" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2">

</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to create a third simple model class (besides `Emp` and `Dept`) which will contain `Deptno` and list of all its employee's names. Let's call it `EmpsByDept`. So, now we have:

```
public class Emp
{
    public String Name { get; private set; }
    public String Deptno { get; private set; }

    public Emp(String name, String deptno)
    {
        Name = name;
        Deptno = deptno;
    }
}

public class Dept
{
    public String Deptno { get; private set; }

    public Dept(String deptno)
    {
        Deptno = deptno;
    }
}

public class EmpsByDept
{
    public String Deptno { get; private set; }

    public String Emps { get; private set; }

    public EmpsByDept(String deptno, IEnumerable<String> emps)
    {
        Deptno = deptno;
        Emps = ConcatEmps(emps);
    }

    private String ConcatEmps(IEnumerable<String> emps)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach(var e in emps)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(e);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Also I suggest to use MVVM design pattern and create a view-model for your window which will contain two lists with initial data and `ObservableCollection` wich we will use as the `ItemsSource` of the `DataGrid`:

```
class TestViewModel
{
    public readonly List<Emp> Emps = new List<Emp> { new Emp("emp1", "dept1"), new Emp("emp2", "dept1"), new Emp("emp3", "dept2") };
    public readonly List<Dept> Depts = new List<Dept> { new Dept("dept1"), new Dept("dept2"), new Dept("dept3") };

    public ObservableCollection<EmpsByDept> EmpsByDepts { get; private set; }

    public TestViewModel()
    {
        EmpsByDepts = new ObservableCollection<EmpsByDept>(Depts.GroupJoin(Emps, 
            d => d.Deptno, 
            e => e.Deptno, 
            (dept, emps) => 
            new EmpsByDept(dept.Deptno, emps.Select(e => e.Name))));
    }
}
```

In `TestViewModel` constructor we initialize `ObservableCollection` with results of LINQ query. Now we should set instance of `TestViewModel` as the `DataContext` of your window:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{ 
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new TestViewModel();
    }
}
```

And bind `ItemsSource` of the `DataGrid`to the instance of our `ObservableCollection`:

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=EmpsByDepts}"
              AutoGenerateColumns="True"/>
</Grid>
```

The result would be:[image]

**EDIT:**

An approach without any additional classes:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public readonly List<Emp> Emps = new List<Emp> { new Emp("emp1", "dept1"), new Emp("emp2", "dept1"), new Emp("emp3", "dept2") };
    public readonly List<Dept> Depts = new List<Dept> { new Dept("dept1"), new Dept("dept2"), new Dept("dept3") };
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        EmpsBuDeptDataGrid.ItemsSource = Depts.GroupJoin(Emps,
            d => d.Deptno,
            e => e.Deptno,
            (dept, emps) =>
            new { Deptno = dept.Deptno, Ems = emps.Select(e => e.Name).Aggregate(string.Empty, (s1, s2) => s1 + Environment.NewLine + s2) });

    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. But I forgot to mention that i can't change or or add new classes, lists and xaml code. I can just write the lambda expression. If result can't be shown in DataGrid, i need only to write lamda expression.

Comment: Ok, so you can use an anonymous type in lambda expression and set LINQ result directly to `ItemsSource` of the `DataGrid`. I've edited my answer.